# How to check for empty results in a cursor? (flask + pymysql)

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, pymysql

I dont know how to check for empty results from a cursor.execute.
Say I have a empty table Brand. I do:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Brand")
db.commit()
results = cursor.fetchall()
return render_template("index.html", results = results)
```

and this pops up on the website:
`TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`
Wanted a fix, maybe a if statement to check if the results are empty..

Comment: If you are just trying to get data *out of* a database with your query, you shouldn't be using a `commit` call; that's only for when you're *adding* data. Have you read the [documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)? Also, you won't be able to directly return your database query without *serializing* it.

Comment: I found out just now that its not even a database problem, and I fixed it. Basically I have some logic error in the jinja functions

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
if cursor.rowcount == 0 # empty results
```

And you don't need `db.commit()` as mentioned in the comments.